# Four-dimensional nilpotent Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

How it can be proved, that every four dimensional nilpotent Lie algebra contains a three dimensional abelian ideal?

Comment: To directly prove this, show that a nilpotent derivation of the 3-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra has a kernel of dimension $\ge 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every $4$-dimensional nilpotent Lie algebra over a field $K$ of characteristic zero is either abelian or isomorphic to the direct sum $\mathfrak{n}_3(K)\oplus K$, where $\mathfrak{n}_3(K)$ denotes the $3$-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra, or to the filiform nilpotent Lie algebra $\mathfrak{f}_4(K)$ with adapted basis $(e_1,\ldots e_4)$ and brackets determined by 
$[e_1,e_i]=e_{i+1}$ for $i=2,3$. This is well known and not difficult to show. Obviously, both algebras contain an abelian ideal of dimension $3$. For example, $\langle e_2,e_3,e_4\rangle$ is an abelian ideal in $\mathfrak{f}_4(K)$.

References on this site:

[Four dimensional nilpotent real Lie algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567758/four-dimensional-nilpotent-real-lie-algebras?rq=1)